# Setup DNS server and use it as a domain, within a LAN connection only. (Offline DNS)

Tags: ubuntu, dns

I wanted to change my ipv4 address (172.50.10.1) into somewhat like `www.jamesrin.com` when the clients within the LAN access my server on their respective browsers.

I've searched the browser. According to them, I can just change the hosts file of each of the client within the LAN for then to access my server, with this method. It just works fine.

But that's not what I want. What I want is for clients within the LAN to access my server without changing each clients hosts file using the example above, www.jamesrin.com.

Actually, im really stuck on where to begin with. Do I need to setup DNS server? Btw. I just want it offline mode. within the LAN only.

Do you have any ideas, suggestions? or somewhat tutorial regarding my problem. It would be much appreciated! Thank you!

Answer (score 4):

First so all, I strongly discourage you to use a "real" domain (like `www.jamesrin.com`) for that, even if your LAN is not connected to the internet. I would rather recommend using a domain like `www.jamesrin.lan` or `www.jamesrin.test` which is no valid TLD. (But do not use `.local`, that's reserved for mDNS).

So if you don't want to edit the hosts file of each client, you either could set up a DNS server or use [mDNS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multicast_DNS). Whenever a `.local` domain is needed to be resolved using mDNS, a request is sent to any computer in your local network. And one computer replies to this with his IP.

If Avahi (a Zeroconf/mDNS implementation) is set on your clients (this is usually the case) you can just use a domain like `hostname.local`. If you query this domain, a request is sent using a broadcast and the computer with the hostname `hostname` responds with his IP. So just try changing the server's hostname to `jamesrin` and check whether you can reach `jamesrin.local` (without `www.`) from another computer.

The other option would be to set up a DNS server in your network. Usually there's a DNS server running on your router - maybe you can use that if you can manually add DNS records (or edit the router's hostfile). (But it isn't clear in your question whether you got a router as you write "offline").

Else you need to set up a DNS server on a computer. I would recommend having a look at [this answer on SuperUser.](https://superuser.com/a/1093639)

Comment: I think using mDNS and/or Link-Local Multicast Name Resololution (LLMNR) would be a better idea than setting up a DNS server for just for a single LAN. It could be enabled already on your Ubuntu machine, try pinging with host names (with and without the .local suffix). If they don't respond, start the the systemd-resolved service and try again.

Comment: On the contrary **DO NOT** use a made up TLD for your internal needs, as you risk collision. TLDs happen to be added, some something "not a valid TLD" can become one yesterday. You should instead register a  domain name, and you can use a subdomain, like `local.jamesrin.com` or `home.jamesrin.com` or whatever to name all your local hosts, and handle that with an internal DNS server.